# how to get the document in chrome devtool panel extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm planning to create a new chrome devtool which is somewhat similar to elements tab. The main difference is instead of whole document, I need to get a document inside iframe and I need to display iframe dom in my devtool panel. How to do this? is sourcecode available for something like this or can anyone give some ideas on how to built it? Thanks

Comment: You need to inject content script for accessing document related objects. And pass messages to your extension script (aka background script) via messaging api. [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) ,[Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)

Comment: Another possibility is chrome.debugger API and its [DOM commands](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-3/DOM).

Comment: how to get the document inside my panel? is there any piece of code for that?